# how to express "married in"

Tags: american-english

I think the following sentence might be wrong since "been" used in present perfect. Don't you?

> They have been married in five years.

I think this should be fixed as this:

> They have married in five years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should either read:

> They have been married for five years

(which means their wedding day was five years ago), or:

> They will be married in five years

(which means their wedding will happen five years from now).

Notice the change in preposition, from *for* (when referring to the past) to *in* (when referring to the future).

As an aside, that's one heckuva long engagement...

Comment: Off-topic, but I was engaged for 7 years, so 5 seems quite a rush :P

Comment: How about that "They will marry in five years" ? And "they have married for 5 years".

Comment: "They will marry in five years" is fine. "They have married for 5 years" is not; the word _married_, when used to describe the state of a couple, uses _have been married_, not _have married_.

Comment: But it might be they are divorced right now. Then may i use "have married"?

Comment: @user1917217 In the case of when they are now divorced, you would say "They **were** married **for** five years."

Comment: There are only 2 cases where "They have married for 5 years" is correct: either their marriage ceremony lasted 5 years, or "they" are church member or civil servants that have spent the last 5 years uniting people in marriage.

Comment: But note you could say, "They married 5 years ago."

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Reminds me of the old joke: The maid tells a Hollywood actress, "There's a bishop at the door who says that he once married you." And the actress replies, "Hmm, I'm pretty sure I was never married to a bishop."

Comment: @Jay what does joke means?

Comment: @user19 - The first person is saying that the bishop conducted the marriage ceremony. The actress is interpreting the word _married_ in the other way. It's a play on words.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the confusion here is the difference between married as a verb, or as an adjective.

"Married" can be an adjective referring to the state of a person or couple, being the opposite of single.  These two people are married.  These two people are a married couple.  I am married.  I am married to a wonderful person.  In this case you can use the word "for" to indicate the period of time during which they were married.  They have been married for five years.  They were married for five years, before getting divorced.  She and I were married for five years before she passed away.

"Marry" is also a verb referring to the process of changing from being single to being married, usually by means of a wedding ceremony.  In this case you can use the word married to refer to this in the past tense.  Today is my wedding anniversary, my wife and I were married five years ago today.  You can also use the word "in" to refer to this event in the future.  My fiancee and I will be married in five years, after we graduate from university.  They will marry in five years.

Some of the other posts and comments might be confusing by referring to another meaning of "marry".  Marry can also be a verb referring to the person who performs a wedding ceremony.  The rabbi married the couple.  The captain of a ship can marry people.  In this context the sentence "They have married for 5 years" could be construed to mean "There are some people, (a group of priests for example), that have been marrying various couples over a period of five years." So whereas your sentence is technically correct in that context, no one would ever say it that way.

Comment: To use it as a verb, your sentences could be "... my wife and I *married* five years ago today." and "My fiancee and I will *marry* in five years."

Comment: Good point, Galactic.